# How to stop the service of nuxt js with npm command

Tags: nuxt.js

I can start the service of nuxt js with `npm run start`, but how i can stop the service with npm command? By the way, I don't want to use pm2.

Comment: do you run it as a detach process (`npm run dev &`) ?  if yes, look on `kill` command (e. `kill -9 <pid>`)

Answer (score 7):

you need to find the process id (PID) of your current `npm run start` instance:

```
pgrep -f npm
```

and then `kill` that process:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

or, directly run the following shortcut:

```
pgrep -f npm | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Also see the `pidof` command.